# How can I link from a dokuwiki wiki article to a mantis ticket?

Tags: wiki, mantis, dokuwiki

I would like to link from a dokuwiki article to a mantis ticket and an overview of tickets

I have the latest versions of mantisbt, dokuwiki and the mantis plugin for doku wiki. Also I have integrated dokuwiki in mantis.

The dokuwiki config looks at the moment like the following

[image: doku wiki config]

The address of mantis is: testserver/mantisbt/
The address of dokuwiki is: testserver/dokuwiki

What´s the meaning of "Username for Mantis"? The adminstrator of mantis?

The following descriptions shows the way to link to the tickets and the ticket overview:

http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:mantis#usage

In my mantis I have the following structure

mantisbt/testproject/ticket

so in an wiki article I linked {{mantisbt>testproject}}, like the descriptions says, to show an overview of tickets. but it does not work

so my questions are:

1. What do I have to configure?
2. What do I have to write in an aritcle to show an overview of tickets of the project?
3. What do I have to write in an article to link to a special ticket?

Thanks 
Best wishes
Christine

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work'?

Comment: I ment that I see a 404 page. But I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I ment that I see a 404 page. But I solved the problem.

The right config is:

Mantisserver:testserver/mantisbt/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl

A username for mantis: myMantisName

A password: myMantisPassword

Than I had to override the syntax.php in dokuwiki/lib/plugins/mantis with the syntax.php the integration documentation descipes: -> [dokuwiki mantis integration](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3aissue:7075%3aintegration_with_dokuwiki)

Now I can open a wiki article and with the following syntax I can link to the mantis ticket 1:

~~Mantis:1~~